# How to fetch records with a number of consecutive associated records?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

books

```
+----+---------+
| id | title   |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Title 1 |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Title 2 |
+----+---------+
```

events

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | title_id | name    | datetime                                  |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1        | event 1 | current_timestamp                         |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 1        | event 1 | current_timestamp - interval '30 minutes' |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
| 3  | 2        | event 2 | current_timestamp                         |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
| 4  | 2        | event 2 | current_timestamp - interval '5 minutes'  |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
| 5  | 2        | event 3 | current_timestamp                         |
+----+----------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I want to produce a table which fetches books which have two or more consecutive events of a given name within a given time period.

With the above data, if I were to say the I was looking for 2 consecutive events of name "event 2" in the last 5 minutes, that would produce:

```
+----+---------+
| id | title   |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Title 2 |
+----+---------+
```

Books with 2 or more consecutive events of name "event 1" within the last 10 minutes would produce nothing, etc.

Would appreciate any insight. I've been trying with lateral queries, but cannot figure out the consecutive part of the query.

Comment: Can you update the sample rows with an example of non-consecutive events?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ -- there are a series of non-consecutive events as "event 2", "event 2", "event 3". If I were looking for books with 3 consecutive events, nothing would show up. The number of consecutive events is variable and can be determined by an interval, too (in last 5/10/15/20 minutes).

Comment: You are probably using the word "consecutive" wrong then or at least differently than what I understand it means. The 3 events (with id 3,4,5 and names 'event 2', 'event 2', 'event 3') look consecutive to me and all 3 are in the last 5 minutes. Perhaps you mean "2 events in the last 5 minutes" as 2 events with same name.

Comment: Perhaps. I mean consecutive of a given type. Not sure how that is confusing. The records are consecutive.. but there are also consecutive records of a given type within those. Either way, I'm sure you grasp what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() setting a partition by name and ordering by datetime.

Then fetch these rows with a row number >= 2.

```
create table books (id int, title text);
insert into books values (1, 'title1'), (2, 'title2');

create table events(id int, title_id int, name text, datetime timestamp);
insert into events values
(1, 1, 'event1', current_timestamp),
(2, 1, 'event1', current_timestamp - interval '30 minutes'),
(3, 2, 'event2', current_timestamp),
(4, 2, 'event2', current_timestamp - interval '5 minutes'),
(5, 2, 'event3', current_timestamp);

with x as
(
    select id, title_id, name, datetime,
           row_number() over (partition by name order by datetime) rn
    from   events 
    where  datetime >= current_timestamp - interval '5 minutes'
)
select   max(rn) as id, name
from     x
where    rn >= 2
group by name;

id | name  
-: | :-----
 2 | event2
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=62a03d4576b8b6336fb9fba914984523)*

Comment: One question, though - the output I was looking for is a list of books with the conditions on those associated events. Seems like I'll have to merge what you have into a join query? never used `with` or `partition` or even `row_number()` so think I have a lot to learn!

Comment: Yes, this returns a list of names, you can join it with book's table to get all columns.